# Jquery "greater than" symbol

Tags: javascript, jquery, dwr

When I use below notation with '>' in line

```
$('#tablesorter > tbody')
```

in code

```
var message;
myService.getUsers({ callback : function(str) { 
    message= jQuery.parseJSON(str);
}}); 

$.each(message, function() {

    $('#tablesorter > tbody').append(
    '<tr><td>' + this.name
    + '</td><td>' + this.surname
    + '</td>' + '</tr>');
});
```

Note: `myservice` is a dwr service, don't know if it is related

I have error in chrome console

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: &gt;
```

`&gt;` means `>`

When I deleted the `>` the error disappears but it does not work as expected

Comment: I have a bit of doubt that it is the problem. Can you post a reproducible snippet of code on jsFiddle?

Comment: I think you use a templating system which transforms the code. What's your complete server solution ?

Comment: Could you give more details on "does not work as expected"? Do you mean that it does not work the way you thought it would, or it does not work the way you hoped it would? `>` in the selector grabs the direct descendant.

Comment: Can you copy the code from the browser source?

Comment: @ExplosionPills dwr is a framework to do ajax calls from server.

Comment: Your problem isn't in the script, but in the way you send it : dwr (I don't know why) is encoding the javascript as if it was html.

Comment: @JohnP i include one page into another in runtime by clicking somewhere so i can use only main pages source code, my script can not be seen when i right click -> view page source, is there another way to see page source

Comment: @dystroy i think you are right,but how can i send it correctly?

Comment: @tuxi I'm sorry : this is a problem specific to dwr and I never used dwr.

Comment: @tuxi just echo it out. Or if you're using ajax, look at the console and paste the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wherever you're outputting your code, it's getting transformed to automatically escape. Perhaps you have a templating language in between.

You need to either store all of your javascript code in a separate file (the best solution), or find a way with your pages (JSP?) to disable output escaping.

Answer (score 4):

the greater than `>` symbol is used in CSS selectors (which jQuery selectors are based on) to indicate a "direct descendent".

[Documentation](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/childselector)

The code you posted works fine, the `>` symbols in there would not cause any errors.